# Filling rows of the dataframe with calculation results

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a large txt file, that looks like this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05jd9.png)

There are five columns in the file: code, type, date, quantity, Timing.

I'm creatig  a new file with eight columns: code, type, ddc, ond, date, timing_с, ft, nd. I need to fill it with data.
Below is something like an algorithm:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['code', 'type', 'date', 'ond', 'date_n', 'timing_с', 'ft', 'nd']

df = pd.read_csv("myfile.txt") #Here I read the source file
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    if row['Timing'] == 17: #Here I look what value is in the cell of the 
    #column "Timing"
```

For example, if i have timing = 17 in file "myfile.txt", i create new row in my new file with eight columns, where in columns "code", "type", "date" I copy value from old file , In column "nd" i'm copy value from column "quantity ". And i need to made this 17 time. In the column "ond" i'm need to indicate number of day. In the column "date_n" i'm distribute days. At the same time, I miss days off and holidays. In the columns "timing_с" and "ft" I do some calculations, which I'll try myself to write in the code. And I need to write the results into a new file. 
[Here is an example for the case if timing = 17, code = 0, type = dgv, date = 02.12.2016 , quantity = 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jffJz.png) This is a random row.

In the original file, there are several different values in the Timing column. I think it needs to be done with the condition if, maybe, if I have an example, I can do this for other values.

Answer (score 0):

use `reindex_axis` to create new columns and use boolean slicing to reduce to only where `'Timing'` is `17`

```
df1 = df[df.Timing == 17].reindex_axis(columns, axis=1)
```